# Global namespaced variable: any alternative?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

If there are three objects:

- Object A triggers an event, passing a 'date' parameter;
- Object B triggers an event, passing a 'category' parameter;
- Object C triggers an event, passing a google map 'bounds' parameter;
- Object D listens to both events A, B and C executing a single function that requires the current state of both A (date), B (category) and C (map bounds).

Is there any way around using:

```
window.app = {}; //--> global 
var curDate = app.appState.curDate; 
var curCategory = app.appState.curCategory; 
var curBounds = app.appState.curBounds;
```

I'm not too fond of using Global variables even when they are namespaced, because the user can directly access these variables from the browser and screw the interface.
The back end is still safe, but somehow it doesn't feel right. 
But it doesn't seem as if there is a viable alternative to access both the variables from controller D. 
I've noticed how passing around parameters and making it fit can become a very cumbersome activity, and it doesn't appear to be very maintainable.

Edit: The structure is somewhat like this:

```
App ---> app_dates       ---> datesController (trigger date change event fom view) 
    ---> app_categories  ---> categoryController (trigger category change from view) 
    ---> app_map         ---> mapController (trigger map bounds change from Google map)
    ---> app_home        ---> Listen to the events, send a request to the server with above parameters)
```

Comment: Erm... can't `object D` ask each object for their corresponding values instead each time an event is triggered? Or just store its own copy of each attribute, modify this copy each time an event is triggered? It's hard to guess without seeing a code, even some prototype one.

Comment: I simply create controllers with `var controller = {}`, where I define methods that listen to events that are either triggered by views or other controllers. These controllers create my models and views, but I don't keep a reference to a global `App` object for all my controllers. So how can the browser remember the general state of my app, unless I explicitly pass it to the global App object?

Comment: If I wanted to ask for the state between controllers, it would mean that I need to pass around controller references to each other (which I used to do), but that sort of screws up my architecture.

Comment: Your architecture explanation is not quite clear. How the `appState` gets populated with correct data? Who's querying the `appState`? It's hard to tell how the first code you posted relates to the second.

Comment: The appState is set by the corresponding controller when a view triggers an event (eg. change date). The appState is queried by a separate object that gets a collection of models from the server based on the four parameters that are generated. Contextually, I load events (leisure) from the server based on these three parameters, so each parameter has to be sent on each request, and each view needs to be updated when one of the other views trigger a change. I hope that makes it more clear.

Comment: and what was the question?

Comment: I was looking for an alternative for accessing (get/set) namespaced globals, avoiding making them publicly accessible via the Window object. Passing around certain parameters throughout the entire application seemed no viable alternative in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

Even at Yahoo, they use a single Global variable.
http://yuiblog.com/blog/2006/06/01/global-domination/

I feel that for specific use cases (module objects / variables that need to be accessed from all parts within the application), it is acceptable to use the window global instead of passing around parameters.

In my case, I guess that it is useful to create a sort of "config" object, booting the global into namespaces and assigning default values when the app starts.

Answer (score 0):

try requireJS, one of requireJS purposes is to not pollute the global scope
in requireJS , you can define your state object as below

```
define('appState', [],function(){
   return {
       curDate: null, 
       curCategory: null, 
       curBounds: null,
   }; 
});
```

now for any module that needs or modify the app state, it will just add appState as dependency, it will be passed as a parameter not a global variable, somthing like below

```
define('datesController',['appState'],function(appState){
    var datesController = Backbone.View.extend({
        events:{
            'change #date': 'dateChanged'
        }
        dateChanged: function(){/*here you can access appState and modify it*/},
    });
    return datesController;
});
```

then whenever you need to create datesController object, all you need is to

```
require('datesController', function(datesController){
    var datesControllerObj =  new datesController({});

});
```

this code is a brief on requireJS, you can refer to below tutorial

http://javascriptplayground.com/blog/2012/07/requirejs-amd-tutorial-introduction/

Comment: I use RequireJS thanks, that's not really the issue.